# Crontab and PgAgent to run python script

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, cron, pgagent

I'm a newbie in Postgre and I have this Python Script which convert my excel file into a PD dataframe. After, the data is send into my PostgreSQL Database.

```
..... 
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@host:port/database')

df.head(0).to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists='replace',index=False) #truncates the table

conn = engine.raw_connection()
cur = conn.cursor()
output = io.StringIO()
df.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
output.seek(0)
contents = output.getvalue()
cur.copy_from(output, 'table_name', null="") # null values become ''
conn.commit()

...
```

I Would like the script to be run daily with a crontab or a PgAgent Job. I'm currently having my database on my local machine which will be later transfer to a server. Whats the best way to schedule tasks which I will use later on a online server? Also, Can i run a schedule a PgAgent to run a python script?

Answer (score 0):

Crontab is a very good tool for scheduling tasks that you want to run repeatedly at specific times or on a restart.`crontab -e` allows the current user to edit their crontab file. For example,

```
30 18 * * * python ~/Documents/example.py
```

Will run "example.py" at 18:30 everyday assuming the user is logged in. The program will run with the privileges of whosever crontab file it is, assuming that they are logged in. Crontab is very easy to use/edit, completely reliable and what I use personally for scheduling tasks on my own server.